# Convergence of $\int\frac{\arctan x}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, infinitesimals

I can't find function to bound this integral in the intervals from $1$ to $+\infty$, to prove if it converges.
$$
\int _1^{\infty }\frac{\arctan x}{x}dx
$$

Any idea?

How can I refute this if it is not converges?
Thanks (:

Comment: Is that $\;x^x\;$ in the denominator?

Comment: the integral does not converge on $(1,+\infty)$

Comment: edited - only x

Comment: $\frac{tan^{-1}(x)}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2x} + \cdots$  for $x$ large. so it not inetgrable on $(1, \infty).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timbuc already provided a method to show that the integral diverges. We can also give an asymptotic equivalent. Integrating by parts, we have $$\int_1^R\frac{\arctan(x)} x\mathrm dx=\left[\ln x\cdot\arctan x \right]_{x=1}^R-\int_1^R\frac{\ln x} {1+x^2}\mathrm dx=\ln(R)\arctan(R)-\int_1^R\frac{\ln x} {1+x^2}\mathrm dx.$$
Since $0\lt \ln (x) \lt x^{1/2}$ for $x$ large enough, we get 
$$\int_1^R\frac{\arctan(x)} x\mathrm dx\overset{R\to \infty} {\sim}
\ln(R)\frac{\pi}4.$$

Answer (score 8):

Since the numerator is ascending, we get

$$\frac{\arctan x}x\ge\frac{\arctan 1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{4x}$$

and the integral of the right side diverges...